# UL-LI sorting not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have following scenario where we can drag and drop to student within seats. In following image we can see that white color image representing a seat and image of boy and girl showing student on seat.

I'm able to move student to other student seat when a student present on that seat. Which we can see in following image. There is a blank seat indicating that seat is blank and on a seat there are two student sharing a seat.

[enter link description here](http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1pzxAYB6iBT6XhTuBOeMhAtEtB4fiR)

But if there is no student on seat that time drag and drop not working properly. Here not working properly means it will not work when we drag a student and drop on a seat but if we drag and drop below seat then it working.

[enter link description here](http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1JOVQKYmRMVK7UCIRK6GnRVzgRNrw0)

So here I want that when I drag a student on a blank seat and leave mouse then it will sit on that seat?

I am using jquery sortable plugin with jquery version `1.11`

Following snippet code of html:

```
<ul class="list-inline text-center connectedSortable" id="sortable">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2"><img src="images/student.png" alt="girl_student_image" class="student">
      <div class="studentname">ID - ABC2</div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 "><img src="images/girl_student.png" alt="student_image" class="student">
      <div class="studentname">ID - ABC3</div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2"><img src="images/student.png" alt="girl_student_image" class="student">
      <div class="studentname">ID - ABC4</div>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-inline text-center" id="sortable"></ul>
```

Code to initiate plugin

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    cancel: "div.studentname",
    cursor: "move",
    distance: 5,
    items: "> li > ",
    revert: true,
    scroll: false,
    tolerance: "pointer",
    });
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
```